# Sonata Media Bundle Installation error

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

'm trying to install sonata media bundle on a symfony 3.3.6

I'm folowing this doc : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html

But I have an error when i'm using this command line, to generate DB : php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

the error message :

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]   Unknown column type "json" requested.
>   Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with
>   \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the
>   known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this
>   error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot
>   to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use
>   AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineType   Mapping() or have your custom
>   types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is
>   empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping
>   information.

my config.yml is taken from the documentation. I reviewed all such articles and nowhere can I find an answer. Why does this error occur? Help please, I'm starting to be disappointed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add json type in your doctrine configuration:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      types:
          json:     Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```

In your config file, you have doctrine section twice.
The first one is applied:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

and you didn't define the JSON type there.

Comment: I'm have this constructions

Comment: You have doctrine section twice. It's unacceptable. you have to merge this configuration. the first one is applied and you don't have JSON type there.

Comment: OMG! I had suspicions, but I'm new to the symphony, thank you very much!

Comment: Now, I'm trying do command `code` php bin/console doctrine:schema:update

Comment: And have error php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException' with message 'Unrecognized options "naming_strategy, auto_mapping" under "doctrine.orm"' in W:\domains\localhost\blog\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode.php:317

Comment: In the case of having entity managers you have to specify the auto_mapping for entity manager. I guess with naming_strategy is the same.

Comment: That's what I did not understand :(

Comment: Where and what to indicate? Sorry, I'm new to this business

Comment: And I do not understand how you can deal with this all, if everything is done according to documentation and does not work ???

Comment: Just remove this 2 lines from the configuration

Comment: If my post doesn't help then just create a new question and you will get more attention to your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml" }
    - { resource: sonata_classification.yml }
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: ru

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

#Cache
doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        my_markdown_cache:
            type: file_system
            file_system:
                directory: /tmp/doctrine_cache

sonata_admin:
    title: My Blog Admin


sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]

doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
                    SonataMediaBundle: ~


    dbal:
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

sonata_media:
    # if you don't use default namespace configuration
    #class:
    #    media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
    #    gallery: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
    #    gallery_has_media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
    db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr it is mandatory to choose one here
    default_context: default # you need to set a context
    contexts:
        default:  # the default context is mandatory
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
                - sonata.media.provider.vimeo

            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

    cdn:
        server:
            path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

    filesystem:
        local:
            directory:  "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media"
            create:     false

sonata_media:
    providers:
        image:
            resizer: sonata.media.resizer.square

doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
                    SonataMediaBundle: ~
```